# Docker login failing (at most 1 argument)

Tags: docker

I am failing to login to a remote docker registry using a command of the form:

```
docker login –u my-username –p my-password registry.myclient.com
```

The error I get is the following:

```
"docker login" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker login --help'.

Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

How can login to the remote registry?

Comment: Did you escape the special characters from your password?

Comment: Did you try not passing the `-p my-password` at all?

Comment: @BMitch The command with no password argument results in the same error. There are no unusual characters in the password, just letters and digits.

Comment: Check your dashes - the `–` character in `–u` and `–p` is not a dash but a different hyphen symbol.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have tacks in front of your options, it's some other dash like character. Try this instead:

```
docker login -u my-username -p my-password registry.myclient.com
```

While it looks similar, `-u` and `-p` are not the same as `–u` and `–p`.

Comment: wow, how did you figure that out? I copied and pasted from a set of instructions that I guess had a bogus fake "dash" character; thanks for noticing.

Comment: When rereading the error message, the "at most 1 argument" indicates that the user and password weren't being processes as options. It's hard to see, but the dash is a bit longer in the code you copied. Likely the result of a web page or text editor trying to make the content pretty.

Comment: "how did you figure that out?" - Well, if you have a closer look, you actually can **see** that the `–u`-dash is longer than the `my-username`-dash.

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me if ci environment is in play:

```
echo ${MVN_PASSWORD} | docker login -u ${MVN_USER} --password-stdin ${MVN_URL}
```

these variables need to be set up via **Settings > CI/CD > Variables** (gitlabci example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

I saved the password in a file called `my_password.txt`.

Then, I ran the following command:

```
cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://{YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.{YOUR_AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: thx, maybe not  the most secure way but it works in windows 10 you can use `type` instead of `cat`

Comment: I tried that, [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate - getting this error in local.